# asp.net mvc + entity framework и сборка мусора

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, сборщик-мусора

Есть ли отличие в плане производительности между написанием

```
HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActioinResult Index()
    {
        var model;
        using(UserContext db = new UserContext())
        {
            var users = db.Users;
            foreach(User item in users)
            {
                // Какое-то действие над каждым item
                // и инициализация model.
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

И

```
HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model;
        var users = db.users;
        foreach(User item in users)
        {
            // Какое-то действие над каждым item
            // и инициализация model.
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(model);
    }
    private var db = new UserContext();
    protected override Dispose(bool isDisposed)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

В первом случае при КАЖДОМ запросе клиента, сервер открывает соединение с бд, вычисляет каждый item, закрывает соединение и возвращает представление.

А во втором случае тоже при КАЖДОМ запросе будет соединение с бд, вычисление и закрытие соединения? Или клиент совершит запрос, сервер обработает, а соединение оставит не выключенным (чтоб при следующем запросе клиента, не тратить время на установку соединения с БД)?

Comment: Объект DbContext, который вы используете в программе и реальные соединения не связаны так, как вы себе это представляете. EF сам управляет соединениями и ему все равно, вызвали вы Dispose, когда вы его вызвали и был ли вызов вообще. Поэтому лучше первый вариант, он более красивый с точки зрения его чтения.

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу сейчас найти ссылку на MSDN, но в документации к Entity Framework указано, что при использовании в ASP.Net время жизни контекста должно быть минимальным, то есть создание и освобождение контекста предпочтительнее в рамках одного метода контроллера

Answer (score 0):

Да, во втором случае соединение тоже будет закрыто в конце обработки запроса.

Второй вариант предпочтителен в случае, когда нужен базовый класс контроллера, от которого наследуют другие:

```
public class BaseDbController : Controller
{
  private UserContext db;
  protected UserContext Db
  {
    get
    {
      if (db == null)
        db = new UserContext();
      return db;
    }
  }  

  protected override Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposing && db != null)
      db.Dispose();
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
}

public class HomeController : BaseDbController
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    var model;
    var users = Db.users;
    foreach(User item in users)
    {
      // Какое-то действие над каждым item
      // и инициализация model.
    }
    Db.SaveChanges();
    return View(model);
  }
}
```